# How to get the highest element in absolute value in a numpy matrix?

Tags: python, numpy

Here is what I am currently doing, it works but it's a little cumbersome:

```
x = np.matrix([[1, 1], [2, -3]])
xmax = x.flat[abs(x).argmax()]
```

Comment: It looks pretty elegant to me...? Is flat slow or something?
Because honestly this looks really nice.

Answer (score 46):

The value you're looking for has to be either `x.max()` or `x.min()` so you could do

```
max(x.min(), x.max(), key=abs)
```

which is similar to aestrivex's solution but perhaps more readable? Note this will return the minimum in the case where `x.min()` and `x.max()` have the same absolute value e.g. `-5` and `5`. If you have a preference just order the inputs to `max` accordingly.

EDIT: Just to clarify, the idea is to leverage the `numpy` methods to reduce down to just two values and then use the `key` feature of the builtin `max` to arbitrate, since `key` is not supported by the `numpy` methods.

Comment: No, the answer is specifically the most extreme signed value

Answer (score 10):

The most compact way would probably be:

```py
x_max = x.flat[np.abs(x).argmax()]
```

By default, the `.argmax()` method operates directly on the flattened array (taken from the [NumPy documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.max.html)). So the operation looks for the maximum absolute value of the n-dimensional array `np.abs(x)`.

Comment: This answer isn't right: It fails to return the correct value when the largest magnitude is negative.  e.g. this will return 8 for the array [-8,1], but 8 isn't in the array!

Comment: You are correct. I edited my answer and corrected the execution times.

Answer (score 9):

This one computes the absolute max'es fast - respecting an arbitrary `axis` argument in the same way as `np.max` and `np.argmax` themselves do.

```
def absmaxND(a, axis=None):
    amax = a.max(axis)
    amin = a.min(axis)
    return np.where(-amin > amax, amin, amax)
```

For long arrays its about 2.5x faster than `a.flat[abs(a).argmax()]` even for the simple case `axis=None` - because it doesn't render abs() of the original big array.

Answer (score 6):

I was looking for a way to get the signed values of the maximum absolute values of an N-dimensional array along a specified axis, which none of these answers handle. So, I put together a function to do it. No promises, but it works as far as I've tested it:

```
def maxabs(a, axis=None):
    """Return slice of a, keeping only those values that are furthest away
    from 0 along axis"""
    maxa = a.max(axis=axis)
    mina = a.min(axis=axis)
    p = abs(maxa) > abs(mina) # bool, or indices where +ve values win
    n = abs(mina) > abs(maxa) # bool, or indices where -ve values win
    if axis == None:
        if p: return maxa
        else: return mina
    shape = list(a.shape)
    shape.pop(axis)
    out = np.zeros(shape, dtype=a.dtype)
    out[p] = maxa[p]
    out[n] = mina[n]
    return out
```

Comment: Good answer !! I would change    p = abs(maxa) **>** abs(mina) to    p = abs(maxa) **>=** abs(mina)

Answer (score 3):

***EDIT***: My answer is off-topic, sorry. As Ophion pointed out this would return the index, not the value - you have to use `flat` with my "`xmax`" (which is really "`xmaxInd`") to get the proper value. Ergo I think your solution is best.

---

After experimenting a bit I realized you can just do this:

```
x = np.matrix([[1,1], [2,-3]])
absX = abs(x)
xmax = argmax(absX)
```

It seems that numpy allows you to take the `abs` as well as the `argmax` of a matrix. How convenient!

`timeit` checks:

```
def meth1():
    x = np.matrix([[1,1],[2,-3]])
    xmax = x.flat[abs(x).argmax()]

def meth2():
    x = np.matrix([[1,1],[2,-3]])
    xmax = argmax(abs(x))

t1 = timeit.Timer("meth1()","from __main__ import meth1")
t2 = timeit.Timer("meth2()","from __main__ import meth2")
```

`mean(t1.repeat(1,100000))` gives `Out[99]: 7.854323148727417`
`mean(t2.repeat(1,100000))` gives `Out[98]: 7.7788529396057129`

So `meth2()` is slightly faster. Probably because it doesn't involve calling `flat`.

Comment: This returns 3, not -3, not really what the question is asking.

Comment: @Ophion that's a good point, I got confused by the indices. I think you do have to use `flat` then.

Answer (score 2):

pardon the necro, but i can't seem to comment on [JoeCondron](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3868428/joecondron)'s answer.

I like:

```
max(x.min(), x.max(), key=abs)
```

but i believe it can be simplified further:

```
max(x, key=abs)
```

seems to work for me (or for non-1D) :

```
max(x.flat, key=abs)
```

Comment: This works but is looping over the array in native Python and so would be 1000sx slower than my solution for large arrays. The idea is to leverage the numpy methods to reduce down to just two values and then use the `key` feature of the builtin `max` to arbitrate.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that I could think of, which looks even worse, is:

```
xmax=x[np.unravel_index(abs(x).argmax(), x.shape)]
```

Answer (score 0):

I use it

```
dt = np.random.rand(50000,500)-0.5
# ur
xmax = dt.flat[abs(dt).argmax()] #230 ms

# new
newdt = np.array([dt.min(),dt.max()]) # 56ms
xmax = newdt.flat[abs(newdt).argmax()] # 4ms
```

it is almost 4 times faster (60 ms against 230)!!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get this value for a 2D numpy array, you can also do the following:

```py
x[np.arange(len(x)), np.abs(x).argmax(axis=1)]
```

For example if your `x` looks like this:

```py
x = np.array([[  -1, -10],
              [ -40,  -5],
              [ -10,  15],
              [  11,  35]])
```

and you want to get the maximum value for each row disregarding the sign, the result would be `np.array([-10, -40, 15, 35])`.

Answer (score -1):

I think this is a pretty straightforward way, which might be slightly better if code readability is your primary concern.  But really, your way is just as elegant.

```
np.min(x) if np.max(abs(x)) == abs(np.min(x)) else np.max(x)
```