# get maximum of absolute along axis

Tags: python, numpy

I have a couple of `ndarrays` with same shape, and I would like to get one array (of same shape) with the maximum of the absolute values for each element. So I decided to stack all arrays, and then pick the values along the new stacked axis. But how to do this?

#### Example

Say we have two 1-D arrays with 4 elements each, so my stacked array looks like

```
>>> stack
array([[ 4,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 0, -5,  6,  7]])
```

If I would just be interested in the maximum I could just do

```
>>> numpy.amax(stack, axis=0)
array([4, 1, 6, 7])
```

But I need to consider negative values as well, so I was going for

```
>>> ind = numpy.argmax(numpy.absolute(stack), axis=0)
>>> ind
array([0, 1, 1, 1])
```

So now I have the indices I need, but how to apply this to the stacked array? If I just index `stack` by `ind`, numpy is doing something broadcasting stuff I don't need:

```
>>> stack[ind]
array([[ 4,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 0, -5,  6,  7],
       [ 0, -5,  6,  7],
       [ 0, -5,  6,  7]])
```

What I want to get is `array([4, -5, 6, 7])`

Or to ask from a slightly different perspective: How do I get the array `numpy.amax(stack, axis=0)` based on the indices returned by `numpy.argmax(stack, axis=0)`?

Comment: Related: [How to get the highest element in absolute value in a numpy matrix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17794266/how-to-get-the-highest-element-in-absolute-value-in-a-numpy-matrix/27903986)

Comment: @jpp that is not along a given axis, but takes the single overall absolute maximum value.

Comment: Some of the answers deal with axis. You'll notice @Divakar's answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39152275/9209546). In any case, I noted a related post, not a duplicate one.

Comment: You are right, I was just looking at the question and first answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have 2D numpy ndarray, classical indexing no longer applies. So to achieve what you want, to avoid brodcatsting, you have to index with 2D array too:

```
>>> stack[[ind,np.arange(stack.shape[1])]]
array([ 4, -5,  6,  7])
```

Comment: This is basically taking the diagonal of my `stack[ind]`. However, I assume yours is more efficient?

Comment: Exactly, the other way is to use `np.diag(stack[ind])`, but I don't know how to extend diagonal approach for higher dimensions, which is simple in approach presented above.

Comment: I solved it be flattening the n-dim input arrays and then reshaping to the original shape at the end.

Comment: And yes, it is faster (about 2 times) ;)

Answer (score 4):

The stacking operation would be inefficient. We can simply use `np.where` to do the choosing based on the absolute valued comparisons -

```
In [198]: a
Out[198]: array([4, 1, 2, 3])

In [199]: b
Out[199]: array([ 0, -5,  6,  7])

In [200]: np.where(np.abs(a) > np.abs(b), a, b)
Out[200]: array([ 4, -5,  6,  7])
```

This works on generic n-dim arrays without any modification.

Comment: What if you have more than just two arrays?

Comment: @Feodoran I guess then @ Kicaj's soln would work for you.

Comment: For more than two arrays one can iteratively apply this approach (I used reduce() for that) and still be faster than the stacking operation. Although I don't know if this true in every cases.

Answer (score 0):

For 'normal' Python:

```
>>> a=[[1,2],[3,4]]
>>> b=[0,1]
>>> [x[y] for x,y in zip(a,b)]
[1, 4]
```

Perhaps it can be applied to `array`s too, I am not familiar enough with Numpy.

Answer (score 0):

Find array of max and min and combine using where

```
maxs = np.amax(stack, axis=0)
mins = np.amin(stack, axis=0)
max_abs = np.where(np.abs(maxs) > np.abs(mins), maxs, mins)
```