# pandas: fast custom aggregation

Tags: pandas, numpy, aggregation

I have a time-idexed data that must be resampled:

```
interval = pd.Timedelta(1/8, "s")
resampled_df = df[["T", "N"]].resample(interval).max()
```

it works very fast, **but I need custom aggregation function (extreme) instead of `max`**

```
def extreme_agg(array_like):
    # return max or min - which absolute value is greater
    return max(array_like.max(), array_like.min(), key=abs)

interval = pd.Timedelta(1/8, "s")
resampled_df = df[["T", "N"]].resample(interval).apply(extreme_agg)
```

I tried also

```
resampled_df = df[["T", "N"]].resample(interval).agg(extreme_agg)
```

But both ways are terribly slow.
Do you have any idea how to make it faster?

Or is there a fast equivalent of my `extreme_agg`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use change [this function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39152275/2901002) working with selected minimal and maximal values by [`DataFrame.xs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html), also first are aggregate values by `min` and `max`:

```
np.random.seed(2021)

N = 10000
df = pd.DataFrame({'T':np.random.randint(100, size=N),
                   'N':np.random.randint(100, size=N)},
                  index=pd.timedelta_range(0, freq='100ms', periods=N)).sub(50)
# print (df)
    

def npwhere(df):
    interval = pd.Timedelta(1/8, "s")
    resampled_df = df[["T", "N"]].resample(interval).agg(['max','min'])
    amax = resampled_df.xs('max', axis=1, level=1)
    amin = resampled_df.xs('min', axis=1, level=1)
    return pd.DataFrame(np.where(-amin > amax, amin, amax), 
                                index=resampled_df.index,
                                columns=['T','N'])

resampled_df = npwhere(df)
print (resampled_df.head(10))

def extreme_agg(array_like):
    # return max or min - which absolute value is greater
    return max(array_like.max(), array_like.min(), key=abs)

interval = pd.Timedelta(1/8, "s")
resampled_df1 = df[["T", "N"]].resample(interval).agg(extreme_agg)
print (resampled_df1.head(10))

print (resampled_df.equals(resampled_df1))
True
```

---

```
In [206]: %timeit npwhere(df)
12.4 ms ± 46.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [207]: %timeit df[["T", "N"]].resample(interval).agg(lambda x: max(x, key = abs))
306 ms ± 4.47 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [208]: %timeit df[["T", "N"]].resample(interval).agg(extreme_agg)
2.29 s ± 14 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: npwhere solution works perfectly. Despite the resampling is done twice, it uses the built-in fast methods - it is much faster!! thx

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
resampled_df = df[["T", "N"]].resample(interval).agg(lambda x: max(x, key = abs))
```

Comment: Checking, it gives the same answer, it just prefers negative values over positive ones when both exist - i.e. `max([-23, 23], key = abs)` is `-23` while it is `23` for OP and you.

Comment: ummm, understand. then ok.

Comment: @jezrael actually testing more `max` prefers the first value, whie your `absmaxND` prefers positive values only - which would give your (and op's) algorithms a positive bias.

Comment: Interesting research ;)